# How Set-Alias an alias that launches new process of Powershell in new window?

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering if there's a way to create an alias that quickly executes the following:

`Invoke-Item C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

I haven't been able to come up with a better way to launch??

Comment: An alias can only refer to another command _name_. For anything else you need a _function_: `Function foo { Start-Process powershell.exe }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make this file:

   ```
   C:\Users\<yourusername>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.Powershell_Profile.ps1
   ```
2. Put the following code in it:

   ```
   Function Start-Powershell {
       Start-Process powershell.exe
   }
   ```
3. Open a new Powershell window.
4. Type `Start-Powershell`

You can name 'Start-Powershell' (name of the Function) whatever you like. This is your new "Alias" which works in your user environment and with auto-completion.